# Checking if two loops returns a value

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop

I want to check if the two for loops returns a match, if they do nothing happens but if they don't I want a message to be printed out saying something like "A match could not be found". Something like this:

```
if (loop1 == 0 && loop2 == 0) {
    NSLog(@"A match could not be found, please check your spelling");
};
```

My question is therefore, how can I describe the loops so that I can check the value they give?

Here are the loops:

```
    for (SMADoc *aSearch in docs) {
        if ([search isEqualToString:[aSearch leadAuthour]]) {
            //Open the file that is represented by UrlToDoc for that specific object
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:[aSearch urlToDoc]];
        }
    }
} else {
    //The string starts with a number and should be converted to an int and then the array of the numbers should be searched through
    int number = atoi(searchC);
    NSNumber *sNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:number];

    for (SMADoc *nSearch in docs) {
        if ([sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:[nSearch urlToDoc]];
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really confusing. You seem to have missed some `if` statement. And what is `loop1` and `loop2`? What exactly are you trying to check here and where?

Comment: @rmaddy The `loop1` and `loop2` was only meant to be an description of how I thought, and the code above is not the full program only the part I found relevant. I actually managed to solve the provlem by myself, and posted the solution as a comment to @vadian's answer down below. But thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I started by declaring two ints, one for each loop, and then checked if a match was NOT found for each iteration, i.e:

```
![search isEqualToString:[aSearch leadAuthour]]
```

If this was true, the int was increased by one. Then, after the array was iterated through, if the int is equal to the number of objects in the array, I then knew that none of the objects matched and I could print out the "A match could not be found, please check your spelling"-message. This is how it looked like in code:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;    

for (SMADoc *aSearch in docs) {
    if ([search isEqualToString:[aSearch leadAuthour]]) {
        //Open the file that is represented by UrlToDoc for that specific object
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:[aSearch urlToDoc]];
    }
  if(![search isEqualToString:[aSearch leadAuthour]]){
    i++;
}
    if(i == [docs count]) {
  NSLog(@"A match could not be found, please check your spelling");
}
  }
} else {
//The string starts with a number and should be converted to an int and then the array of the numbers should be searched through
int number = atoi(searchC);
NSNumber *sNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:number];

for (SMADoc *nSearch in docs) {
    if ([sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:[nSearch urlToDoc]];
    }
if(![search isEqualToString:[aSearch docNumber]]){
j++;
  }
if(j == [docs count]) {
  NSLog(@"A match could not be found, please check your spelling");
    }

}
```

I don't know if it's allowed to answer your own question, but my intention with this was to provide an answer for someone who might be asking the same question.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile. You can't call a method on an `int`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for noticing! I don't have the code available on this computer so I just wrote it from how I remembered it but will definitely look into it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

As your custom class is KVC compliant you could perform the check simultaneously with NSPredicate without any loop.

The expression means: if `docs` contains an object whose `docNumber` is `number` or `leadAuthour` is `search`, skip the error message

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"docNumber == %i || leadAuthour == %@", number, search];
  if [[docs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count] == 0 {
      NSLog(@"A match could not be found, please check your spelling");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I actually managed to solve the problem another way; For each time `[search isEqualToString:[aSearch leadAuthour]]`or `[sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]`did not match, an ìnt` was increased by one (I used a different int-variable for each check). If the int then was equal to the number of documents in `docs` I knew that there was no match and a message saying this could be printed out!